# How to run a local dtsx package within SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: ssis, ssms

I have created a .dtsx file with the import wizard of SSMS and stored the file in the local file system. I can open this file with SSMS and get its XML content displayed in the Object Explorer.

Now I want to run this file with SSMS. I have tried the right mouse button and searched all available menu items, but could not find a command for executing the .dtsx file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Double-clicking a `.dtsx` file should launch the DTExec GUI.

[image]

If you want to run in SSMS, then you will need to use a [SQL Server Agent](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6639/execute-ssis-packages-from-sql-server-agent/) job.

[image]

[image]

If you see yourself developing and running many packages, use the [SSISDB Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/service/ssis-catalog) to store, manage, and execute packages.

Comment: In my case, Double-clicking didn't launch anything, but using your answer as inspiration, I added the Association that was missing to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ DTExecUI.exe

Answer (score 5):

Updated answer (I suppose this is windows only):

- If you have visual studio, go to extensions, search for "Sql Server Integration Services Projects."  That will just direct you to a download.
- In any case, install the above mentioned... thing.  It's fat, but painless (no options to worry about).
- That will add dtexec to your path.
- dtexec /f "YourPackage.dtsx"